# When I run this code uniqe[0] gets the first letter in words I want it to have the whole word in uniqe[0]

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run this code, `uniqe[0]` gets the first letter in `words`
I want it to have the whole word in `uniqe[0]`.

I have tried `uniqe[0]=words[0]`, but it does not work.

```
count = 0
for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    length = len(words)
    print(words[0])
    if count == 0:
        uniqe=words[0]
    print (uniqe)
    print (uniqe[0])
```

Output

```
Enter the file name: romeo.txt
But
But
B
```

Comment: You need to show what is in `words` variable.

Comment: The line starts with Word ’but’

Answer (score 0):

I'm (still) not sure I understand your question, but here's a guess:

```
fhand = ["But lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fermentum\n",
         "mauris eget mi semper sodales non vitae arcu. Sed dapibus semper elementum.\n",
         "Aenean in felis id turpis pharetra maximus. Fusce pulvinar iaculis nunc, id\n",
         "varius tellus finibus nec. Donec nec dui ullamcorper, elementum dui vitae,\n",
         "tempor nisl.\n"]

count = 0
unique = []  # ADDED
for line in fhand:
    words = line.split()
    if count == 0:
        unique.append(words[0])

print(unique)
print(unique[0])
```

Output:

```
['But', 'mauris', 'Aenean', 'varius', 'tempor']
But
```